# touchmove handler after touchstart handler wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, touch

I have a problem with an touchmove event. When the user touches the display (touchstart) the `touchmove` event handler and `game()` should be executed and if the user leaves the screen everything should be stopped. But then the if conditions for the `collisiondetection` interval won't work right because `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` always have the coordinates of the touchstart and won't update their values when the user moves their finger (touchmove) on the screen. How can I fix this? [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/056y98f0/6/)

```
$("body").on({
    'touchstart mousedown': function (e) {
        $(this).on('touchmove mousemove');

        collisiondetection = setInterval(function() {
            var xp1 = $("#n1").position();
            if (e.pageY >= xp1.top && e.pageY <= xp1.top + cy * 10 && e.pageX >= xp1.left && e.pageX <= xp1.left + cx * 25) {
                console.log("hit"); 
            }
            var xp2 = $("#n2").position();
            if (e.pageY >= xp2.top && e.pageY <= xp2.top + cy * 10 && e.pageX >= xp2.left && e.pageX <= xp2.left + cx * 25) {
                console.log("hit"); 
            }   
        },10);

        game();
    },
    'touchend mouseup': function (e) {
        $(this).off('touchmove mousemove');
    clearInterval(animaterects);
    clearInterval(collisiondetection);
    }
});
```

UPDATE: If I edit it to `'touchstart mousedown touchmove mousemove': function (e) {` the collision detection and the updating coordinates works well but the animation dont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becasue your code doesn't update the coordinates when users move their fingers.

```
$("body").on({
    'touchstart mousedown': function (e) {
        var pageX = e.pageX
        var pageY = e.pageY;
        $(this).on('touchmove mousemove',function(e){
            pageX = e.pageX;
            pageY = e.pageY;
        });

        collisiondetection = setInterval(function() {
            var xp1 = $("#n1").position();
            if (pageY >= xp1.top && pageY <= xp1.top + cy * 10 && pageX >= xp1.left && pageX <= xp1.left + cx * 25) {
                console.log("hit"); 
            }
            var xp2 = $("#n2").position();
            if (pageY >= xp2.top && pageY <= xp2.top + cy * 10 && pageX >= xp2.left && pageX <= xp2.left + cx * 25) {
                console.log("hit"); 
            }   
        },10);

        game();
    },
    'touchend mouseup': function (e) {
        $(this).off('touchmove mousemove');
    clearInterval(animaterects);
    clearInterval(collisiondetection);
    }
});
```